# Envio de objeto simple por intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo una duda simple, quiero mandar un objeto a otra activdad con un `intent`. He estado leyendo en sitios que no se puede, pero a mí me funciona.

Tengo unos `textView` con datos, mi clase objeto `Serializable` y mi segunda actividad.

Lo mando así, tanto dentro del bundle como sin él (solo lo comentado), me funciona.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cuál es la forma correcta? Si luego en la segunda actividad lo modifico y lo vuelvo a enviar con otro simple `intent` valdria, ¿no?

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

i.putExtra("datos",vec);

//Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//bundle.putSerializable("datos",vec);
//i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Lo recibo así:

```
Vehiculo vec;
/*
no lo usamos aun
    if(coche != null){
        vec = (Vehiculo) coche.getSerializable("datos");

        //asginacion
    }
*/

//prueba recibir

intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
vec = (Vehiculo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("datos");

marca.setText(vec.getMarca());
cilindrada.setText(String.valueOf(vec.getCilindrada()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Para no entrar en muchos detalles y ser lo mas simple posible, un `Intent` se usa para iniciar otra `activity`, además de poder iniciar un servicio o realizar mas tareas de ser necesario como enviar información por medio de este.

Por otro lado, un `Bundle` es algo en lo que se pueden pasar varios datos, por ejemplo `int`, `float`, `string`... O cualquier Objeto. Este `Bundle` se pasa a un `Intent` para poder enviar los datos de un `activity` a otra, etc.

A mi parecer lo mejor sería que cargaras los parámetros que deseas pasar en un `Bundle` y lo pones en un `Intent` para poder trabajar con los dos `activity`.

Referencias:

[Intent | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Bundle | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)